# Matlab GUI-Add slider to static text box

Tags: matlab, user-interface

My question is whether there is a way to add a slider to static text.I want to display the content of an array and i want to use a slider so that all elements can be seen.

Comment: You mean a scroll bar?

Comment: It seems that the a scroll bar can not be associated to a `static text uicontrol`. You can use an `edit` uicontrol and setting its `Max` property to a number greater than 1 (it could be the maximum number of lines you expect to have to dispay.

Comment: Yes a scroll bar

Comment: Assuming you're not using the new app engine, for horizontal scrolling you'll likely need to interact with the underlying Java object. See: [Customizing listbox & editbox scrollbars](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-listbox-editbox-scrollbars).